# What are acceptable “relationships with referees”?

Tags: graduate-admissions, graduate-school

I am applying for grad school and need to give referees, and their relationship with me. I am not sure how to phrase things. My referees are:

1. in my previous job, in-direct supervisor, who I had worked for on one project, I report the project to her
2. in my previous job, whom I worked with on one project, but he is the project lead

thanks

Comment: *referees* --- The standard term is "references", with "referees" being the names of the people who peer-review your publications.

Comment: @DaveLRenfro No, both terms are standard.

Answer (score 4):

Assuming that you mean "references", they should be people who know your academic work well. Basically anyone is acceptable as long as they can be expected to give a fair and accurate statement about what you have done and about your probable likelihood of success in the academic program.

Professors, advisors, employers, Lab PIs. etc. are all fine. They need not be supervisors, but can be. Your mom, and uncles, however, aren't the best, nor is a spouse or child. Anyone with whom you have had a professional/academic relationship and has some stature is a good choice.

As for the description, just say it like it is.